# Using field content as part of the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, in one of the fields I stored a string like this:

```
RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), 'Company_Enroll_YYYY-MM-DD.csv')
```

I would like to use it as part of the query that I could call from my c# code, so the query would look like this:

Select ThisField, ...
From mytable

Is this doable?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is this formula stored on only one row, and you want to query this table, including the result of this formula for this row only, along with the results of similar formulas stored on other rows for each of their rows respectively? If you need to do this for more than one row at a time, you're going to need to explain this better. E.g. show more than one formula! Show more than one row! Show more than one column! Show the ultimate results you expect! We can't guess that you want more than one row if you only show us one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just generate a SQL string by nesting.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @t TABLE (formula NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @t(formula) SELECT 
  'RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), ''Company_Enroll_YYYY-MM-DD.csv'')';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' + formula + ', [other columns] 
  FROM dbo.mytable' FROM @t -- WHERE...;

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**EDIT**

Here is one way to handle the multi-row scenario:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE dbo.src(ID INT, formula NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT dbo.src(ID, formula) SELECT 
  1, 'RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), ''Company_Enroll_YYYY-MM-DD.csv'')'
  UNION ALL SELECT 
  2, 'RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), 'Foo_MM.DD.YYYY.csv'')';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL SELECT ID, ' + formula + '
  FROM dbo.src WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ID)
  FROM dbo.src -- WHERE...;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 12, '') + ';';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE dbo.src;
```

This produces an ugly union query:

```
SELECT ID, RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), 'Company_Enroll_YYYY-MM-DD.csv')
  FROM dbo.src WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ID, RMaster.dbo.fnFormatDate (GETUTCDATE(), 'Foo_MM.DD.YYYY.csv')
  FROM dbo.src WHERE ID = 2;
```

You could probably build an awful and much more complicated `CASE` expression dynamically, but as long as there's a good supporting index on ID so that each query is a single-row seek, this should be okay. The calls to the UDF are probably going to kill you more than the rest of the query anyway.

Comment: Thanks you Aaron... But I am not sure about the INSERT. You insert only one record, but the formulas are different for each record... I guess what I need is impossible, isn't it? Or maybe I misunderstand your code?

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem better then.

Comment: OK, I have a reference table. One of its fields contains formatting information for generating various kinds of file names. You saw one example of that data, but it was only one of the patterns I need. From my C# code, I need to call a query that would join another table with that reference (lookup) table and return file names formatted according to the formatting information stored in that field discribed above.